# Booting Debian into Virtualbox or other Virtualization Software

Tags: virtualization

On my laptop, I have `Windows 10` on first disk drive and `Debian 10` on second disk drive with dual-boot functionality. However, is it possible to boot `Debian 10` installation from `Windows 10` through some kind of virtualization software, while `Windows 10` is running?

Comment: Related: [Sharing a hard disk partition with a Linux VM on VirtualBox](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/259147/23408).

Answer (score -1):

Booting into a hard disk installation of Debian from inside Windows 10 is not very easy, unless you use specialised features in VMWare et al.

In your case, you can create a virtual machine inside Virtualbox and boot into it from Windows 10.
But then you won't be able to run it independently.